# Extending solutions to the Dirichlet problem

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables

I got stuck on the following problem.

Let $\Delta = \left\{ |z| \leq 1 \right\} \subset \mathbb{C}$ be the unit disk, and let $r$ be a holomorphic function on $\Delta$ which is smooth on $\bar{\Delta}$.

We seek for a holomorphic function $f$ on $\Delta$ for which 
$$
1 + |r|^2 = |f|^2\quad \text{on the boundary $\partial \Delta$}.
$$
For this Dirichlet problem, there is a unique solution $f$ which doesn’t have zeros in $\Delta$.

Now assume that $r$ is a rational function in $\mathbb{C}$ (meromorphic function on the sphere $\mathbb{CP}^1$). Can we extend $f$ to be a rational function on $\mathbb{C}$? What if $r$ is a polynomial?